# Integral Over functions Differential Entropy

Tags: stochastic-processes, entropy

Suppose there is some function:

\begin{equation}
f(t) = p(x)
\end{equation}

Where $p(x)$ is a PDF over $x$ at $t$. Some examples would be linear regression with error bounds or a Gaussian Process (typically $p(x)$ is gaussian) eg:

[image]

How would one quantify the differential entropy of $x \sim f(t) \ \ st. \ \ t_1 < t < t_2$?

Intuitively I would to do the following:

\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{H}(f(t) | t_1 < t < t_2) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(f(t)) \; d t
\end{equation}

where $H(f(t))$ is the differential entropy of $x$ at $t$.

If my formulation is not clear. I wish to quantify the uncertainty of $x$ over an interval of $t$. Does this have a name?

Comment: Could you please explain what a "pdf over $x$ at $t$" means and how that is related to linear regression?

Comment: @whuber I believe I am describing a stochastic process. $t$ is sometimes referred to as the index often denoting time. $f(t)$ returns to a pdf (probability distribution function) over $x$ at time $t$. 

eg. $t$:=Time; $x:=$ stock price; $p(t_i)$ is the pdf of the stock price at time $t_i$.

I am interested in quantifying the uncertainty about $x$ over a time interval.

Comment: You need to explain what integrating over the index $t$ might mean.  It's hard to determine what you really mean by the differential entropy of a process.

Comment: I believe what I am looking for is Entropy Rate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate